# .Net isn't deserializing stream when sent from Websockets

Tags: c#, javascript, serialization, tcp, websocket

I'm making an application in PhoneGap, and I'm using HTML5 Websockets to send some info to another device (read: sending data to another user who has the app). Users are registered with ID and Username. 
For this, I read that I have to make an TCP/Socket connection. I've tried to use an old socket-chat I once made in school with C#. 
I'm connecting to the socket this way from the app:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:7001");
 ws.onopen = function()
 {
    // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
    ws.send("message");
 };
```

And the server side looks like this (of course isn't the entire code, but the relevant parts)

```
private NetworkStream stream;
    private IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    private TcpListener server;
    public TcpClient client;
    private string username { get; set; } 

private void StartServer()
    {

        int port = Convert.ToInt32(portUser);
        server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port);
        server.Start();


            client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            stream = client.GetStream();
            username = formatter.Deserialize(stream).ToString();
     }
```

The last deserialize-line writes: 
The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 47-45-54-20-2F-20-48-54-54-50-2F-31-2E-31-0D-0A-48 ...

Any other way to deserialize the stream? Or am I using a completely wrong way?

**Edit: working C# way I used to send data between clients in the chatter**

```
        stream = client.GetStream();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, messageobj);
        stream.Flush();
```

Comment: AFAIK stream need to have `EOF` in order to make deserialization to work that is not case here

Comment: @TrevorElliott Well, it used to work with C# clients connecting? Edited my question.